# Django models saving

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

How I can process salary with function from model and save it to year_salary

Example model:

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    salary = models.FloatField()
    year_salary = ArrayField(models.FloatField()
```

And function:

```
def function(salary):
    year_salary = salary * 12
    return year_salary
```

Answer (score 3):

As I understood you want to store an array of year salaries?

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    salary = models.FloatField()
    year_salary = ArrayField(models.FloatField())

    def calculate_year_salary(self):
        return self.salary * 12    

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.year_salary:
            self.year_salary = [self.calculate_year_salary()]
        else:
            self.year_salary.append(self.calculate_year_salary())
        super(Staff, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```